# Merging two df with specific change in R

Tags: r

I have two df:

```
df1                 df2
x  x_lib            y   y_lib
A  apple            1   red
B  banana           2   green
C  mango
```

i want to generate a df that contains

```
x-y   x_lib(y_lib)
A-1   apple(red)
A-2   apple(green)
B-1   banana(red)
B-2   banana(green)
C-1   mango(red)
C-2   mango(green)
```

how can I do this in R please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you merge:

With base R:

```r
merge(df1, df2)
  x  x_lib y y_lib
1 A  apple 1   red
2 B banana 1   red
3 C  mango 1   red
4 A  apple 2 green
5 B banana 2 green
6 C  mango 2 green
```

With `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyr)
expand_grid(df1,df2)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  x     x_lib      y y_lib
  <chr> <chr>  <int> <chr>
1 A     apple      1 red  
2 A     apple      2 green
3 B     banana     1 red  
4 B     banana     2 green
5 C     mango      1 red  
6 C     mango      2 green
```

Then, you build the columns as you show:

```r
library(dplyr)
merge(df1, df2) %>%
  mutate(`x-y` = paste(x,y, sep = "-"), 
         `x_lib(y_lib)` = paste0(x_lib,"(",y_lib,")")) %>%
  select(5:6)
  x-y  x_lib(y_lib)
1 A-1    apple(red)
2 B-1   banana(red)
3 C-1    mango(red)
4 A-2  apple(green)
5 B-2 banana(green)
6 C-2  mango(green)
```

or

```r
library(tidyverse)
expand_grid(df1,df2) %>%
  mutate(`x-y` = paste(x,y, sep = "-"), 
         `x_lib(y_lib)` = paste0(x_lib,"(",y_lib,")")) %>%
  select(5:6)
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  `x-y` `x_lib(y_lib)`
  <chr> <chr>         
1 A-1   apple(red)    
2 A-2   apple(green)  
3 B-1   banana(red)   
4 B-2   banana(green) 
5 C-1   mango(red)    
6 C-2   mango(green)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to iago's excellent answer, you can do it simply using base R.

Merging (exactly as shown before, here to have continuity with naming):

```r
df_merged <- merge(df1, df2)
```

Because you haven't named columns by which the merge is supposed to occur, R will create every possibility (so it will merge each row of df1 with each row of df2).

Creating columns, you can do it two at the time using c() and paste():

```r
df_merged[c("x-y", "x_lib(y_lib)")] <- c(paste(df_merged$x, df_merged$y, sep="-"), paste(df_merged$x_lib, "(", df_merged$y_lib, ")", sep=""))
```

Dropping unnecessary columns:

```r
df_merged <- df_merged[, c("x-y","x_lib(y_lib)")]
```

As a result you will get following dataframe:

```r
df_merged
  x-y  x_lib(y_lib)
1 A-1    apple(red)
2 B-1   banana(red)
3 C-1    mango(red)
4 A-2  apple(green)
5 B-2 banana(green)
6 C-2  mango(green)
```